# Placing a label on runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am placing a label on run time after a div element. Placed it using z-index, but the position of the label is seemed to be fixed, even though i mention as absolute. It is getting moved when i scroll it.Could anyone suggest.

```
$("#button").after($('<span id=label> Testing </span>'))

CSS:
#label
{
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:200px;
Z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. If you do not want it to move when you scroll, use `position: fixed;`

Comment: That's what "absolute" positioning is supposed to do. If you don't want it to move when the body scrolls, you want `position: fixed`.

Comment: If it is a label, why is it a span?

Answer (score 2):

**According to W3C:**

The [`absolute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#absolute) position is "with respect to the box's containing block", meaning that it scrolls with its container. So if I have

```
<body>
   ...
   <p style="position: absolute">STUFF!</p>
   ...
</body>
```

then it will scroll relative to `body`.

The [`fixed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#fixed) position scrolls "with respect to the viewport and does not move when scrolled." It scrolls relative to the viewport, or browser window. So if I have

```
<body>
   ...
   <p style="position: fixed">STUFF!</p>
   ...
</body>
```

then when I scroll, the text will stay put, relative to my browser window.